# New iPad displays iphone app's Launch images as app icon, not App Icon image

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

My app, built only for iPhone, doesn't show Icon correctly in new iPad, which has retina display. While installing the app, app Icon is displayed correctly. But After finishing installation, the app's launch image is displayed as the Icon, not the Icon image.
Since it's not the universal app, there seems to have no place to configure something for iPad device in Xcode.

In iPhones including 3Gs, 4, and 4S, and old iPads, I don't have this problem.

Comment: which version of xcode did you use ? i mean which sdk ?

Comment: What are the names of the icon and launch image files?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 and build target is > iOS 5.0. names of icons are Icon.png and Icon@2x.png and the names of launch images are Default.png and Default@2x.png. It is necessary to include icon images for iPad, named like Icon-72 and Icon-72@2x, even if the app is not built as universal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I've done incorrectly by chance. In app info plist file, Default.png and Default@2x.png was added to "Icon Files" entry. I don't know why. I guess I've manipulated Xcode oddly before.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple Docs on [Application Icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html):

If you’re creating a universal application, you need to supply application icons in all four sizes.

For iPhone and iPod touch both of these sizes are required:

- 57 x 57 pixels **Icon.png**
- 114 x 114 pixels (high resolution) **Icon@2x.png**

For iPad, both of these sizes are required:

- 72 x 72 pixels **Icon-72.png**
- 144 x 144 (high resolution) **Icon@2x.png**

And to keep simple, you should use the recommend names for each icon.  Take a look at [How are the icon files in my application bundle used on iPad and iPhone?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)

The following screenshot was taken from [pinch multimedia iOS 5 icon sizes](http://pinchmultimedia.com/blog/ios-5-icon-sizes-and-names-new-ipad).
[image]

Comment: In what context are you asking do I mean Icon-72@2x.png?

Comment: '144 x 144 (high resolution) Icon@2x.png' You've called two files Icon@2x.png :)

Comment: I believe Icon@2x.png is still used by iPad2.

Comment: So if you're making a universal app, how do you differentiate between the 114x114 iPhone Icon@2x.png and the 144x144 Icon@2x.png ?

Comment: checkout the docs here (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) - your link goes to a 'pre retina-iPad' link which misses out Icon-72@2x.png

Comment: But, my app is not built as universal. Do I need to add Icon-72, Icon-72@2x icon images manually, without using Xcode?

Comment: Yes, you need to add them.  It would make life easier if you add them to the project in Xcode, so the bundle can be signed for deployment.